# How to write a line of code for flipping a coin in one line with 27 characters

Tags: python

I have to code this question in one line for the outcome of flipping a fair coin, with 27 characters allowed only, and the output must be either H or T.

```
import numpy as np

print(__________)
```

I have tried `np.random.randint()` but it always exceeds the allowed characters.

Sorry guys, additional clarification: I am given the above code which cannot be changed. The output should be either "H" or "T".

Comment: are you allowed import statement?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: This is a Quiz question for interview or similar

Answer (score 2):

This is the shortest i could come up with allowing for an import statement.

```
from random import randint as r

print("HT"[r(0,1)])
```